# Selenium Click() not working with scrapy spider

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, click, web-crawler, scrapy

I am trying to scrape links to product pages from a listing page using a scrapy spider. The page shows the first 10 machines and has a button for 'show all machines' that calls some javascript. The javascript is reasonably complicated (i.e. I can't just look at the function and see the url that the button points to). I'm trying to use the selenium webdriver to simulate a click on the button but it isn't working for some reason. When I scrape the product links I only get the first 10, not the complete list.

Can anybody tell me why it doesn't work?

The page I'm trying to scrape is http://www.ncservice.com/en/second-hand-milling-machines

The spider is

```
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.http import Request, FormRequest
from scrapy import log
from scrapy.exceptions import DropItem
from scrapy import signals
from mtispider.items import MachineItem

import urlparse
import time
import MySQLdb
import unicodedata
import re
from mtispider import tools
from selenium import webdriver


class MachineSpider(CrawlSpider):
name = 'nc-spider'
allowed_domains = ['ncservice.com']

def start_requests(self):
    requests = list(super(MachineSpider, self).start_requests())
    requests.append(Request('http://www.ncservice.com/en/second-hand-milling-machines', callback=self.parsencmilllist))
    return requests

def parsencmilllist(self,response):
    hxs=HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    driver= webdriver.Firefox()
    driver.get(response.url)
    try:
        driver.FindElement(By.Id("mas-resultados-fresadoras")).Click()
    except:
        log.msg("Couldnt get all the machines", level=log.INFO)
    ncmachs = hxs.select('//div[@id="resultados"]//a/@href').extract()
    for ncmach in ncmachs:
        yield Request(ncmach,
                      meta = {'type':'Milling'},
                      callback=self.parsencmachine)
    driver.quit()

def parsencmachine(self,response):
    #scrape the machine
    return item
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is that you need to initialize your `Selector` from the webdriver's `page_source` and not the `response` passed into the callback:

```
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider
from scrapy.http import Request
from scrapy import Selector

from selenium import webdriver

class MachineSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'nc-spider'
    allowed_domains = ['ncservice.com']

    def start_requests(self):
        yield Request('http://www.ncservice.com/en/second-hand-milling-machines',
                      callback=self.parsencmilllist)

    def parsencmilllist(self, response):
        driver = webdriver.Firefox()

        driver.get(response.url)
        driver.find_element_by_id("mas-resultados-fresadoras").click()

        sel = Selector(text=driver.page_source)
        driver.quit()

        links = sel.xpath('//div[@id="resultados"]//a/@href').extract()
        for link in links:
            yield Request(link,
                          meta={'type': 'Milling'},
                          callback=self.parsencmachine)

    def parsencmachine(self, response):
        print response.url
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it looks like this may work, except now I get the following error `selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Can't load the profile. Profile Dir: %s If you specified a log_file in the FirefoxBinary constructor, check it for details.` Firefox auto-updated today and it looks like it's broken selenium! I get as far as the firefox window opening, but the page doesn't display and after a while it crashes then scrapy shows the above error.

Comment: @ahc ok, just downgrade firefox to 34.0.5.

Comment: Ok, fixed the firefox problem. Unfortunately the click function still isn't working. The spider only passes 10 machines to `parsencmachine`. The output of `driver.page_source` still contains the view all machines button. Do I need some sort of 'wait' here to give it time to load the full set of machines?

Comment: Got it. The page does need time to reload. A simple solution is to just add `time.sleep(10)` directly after the `click()` function. A more complete solution is discussed [here](http://www.obeythetestinggoat.com/how-to-get-selenium-to-wait-for-page-load-after-a-click.html). Thanks for the answer @alecxe, I'll mark it as correct as it works except for the wait.

Comment: @ahc yeah, there is the need of an explicit wait here. Thanks for sharing!